# How to execut a javascript function in a php table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a small web page.

On this page I have a table and created a function that takes the id and returns an image.

Everything is working correctly, the issue is that whenever I click on a line that function is executed.

I just wanted the function to execute when I click on the attached column of id's. (Second Column)

Does anyone can help me please?

Realized my doubts?

Thank you all.

---

```
    <script>
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;

                                        //use ajax to post id to ajax.php file
                                        $.post("ajax.php", { id:id }, function( data ) { 
                                              //add result to a div and create a modal/dialog popup similar to alert()
                                              $('<div />').html(data).dialog();
                                        });

                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
</script>
```

Comment: Well you are attaching it to every row, perhaps you should only attach it to the second cell using `table.rows[i].cells[1]`

Comment: you are adding the onclick event to the row.

If you want the onclick event on second td, add that onclick event to second td

Comment: And you're on the right track using a function to create the click handler so you use the right row, but there's no reason to recreate that `createClickHandler` function on every loop iteration! Just create it once.

Comment: `var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("td");` Um.... That'll give you every `td`, not every row.

Comment: Thank you all for reply's. I tried the code (table.rows[i].cells[1]) that @Jonathon say, but isn't working :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using jQuery, so...let's use jQuery:

```
// Process the code on document ready
$(function() {
    // Hook "click" on the table, but only actually call the handler if the
    // click passed through the second cell in a row
    $("#tableId").on("click", "tr td:nth-child(2)", function() {
        // Do the post
        $.post("ajax.php", {
            id: $(this).text() // <== Getting the id by getting the text of the clicked cell
        }, function(data) {
            //add result to a div and create a modal/dialog popup similar to alert()
            $('<div />').html(data).dialog();
        });
    });
});
```

Differences:

1. We're doing it on document ready rather than window load, which is a lot earlier.
2. Using a delegated handler rather than a handler on each table cell.
3. Using `:nth-child(2)` to get the second `td` in the row. Note that this assumes you will only have cells in your row (which is 99.9999% true; `template` is allowed there too, though).
4. Using `$(this).text()` to get the `id`

Here's an example just showing the `id` rather than doing the `$.post` call:

```js
// Process the code on document ready
$(function() {
    // Hook "click" on the table, but only actually call the handler if the
    // click passed through the second cell in a row
    $("#tableId").on("click", "tr td:nth-child(2)", function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: very thanks for your answer. I tried your code, but isn't work :S 
Doesn't retrieve anything...

Comment: You know why this happen?

Comment: @rpirez: I'm very surprised to see that jQuery interprets the `tr td:eq(1)` in what seems to be an incorrect way (only matches the second cell of the **first** row). But `:nth-child` works here, see the update.

Comment: very thanks for you help. It work's fine. You save my day Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

put the click handler on the cell instead of the row

```
var currentRow = table.rows[i];
var cell = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
var createClickHandler = function(cell) 
    {
        return function() { 
            var id = cell.innerHTML;
            //use ajax to post id to ajax.php file
            $.post("ajax.php", { id:id }, function( data ) { 
                  //add result to a div and create a modal/dialog popup similar to alert()
                  $('<div />').html(data).dialog();
            });
         };
    };
cell.onclick = createClickHandler(cell);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried you code, but give me that error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB\ajax.php on line 10

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() is a php function. The first parameter must be a resource linking to a database.
Maybe create a new stackoverflow question explaining your ajax.php for that.

Answer (score 0):

why you have not try with the id means give id of each td and whatever you want on the function of onclick you can do that